# Using flot (or another canvas plotting javascript package) in a modal dialog box

Tags: jquery, canvas, flot, jqmodal

I'm trying to to display a chart (generated using flot) in a modal dialog box. The plot is a blown up version of a smaller chart. From my initial attempts I can't seem to display a chart.

Would this be a limitation of the canvas tag?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so a solution I found was to create a second php page where the flot chart is printed and then call that page from the jqmodal dialog.

Hope this helps. There is probably a better solution, but this hack seems to have the desired effect.